# Running a twisted sample script on Python 3.7 (macOS) raises exception

Tags: python, macos, exception, twisted

I'm tryign to have twisted **19.7.0** running on **macOS Catalina 10.15.1** with **Python 3.7.5**.

I choose the chat sample to verify if it works (see source chat.py in https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/servers.html).

Following documentation I've installed `twisted` using `virtualenv`.

I start the script and then I test it with `telnet`:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8123
```

It follows the stacktrace:

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/giacomo/.virtualenvs/twisted-samples/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 86, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/giacomo/.virtualenvs/twisted-samples/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 122, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/giacomo/.virtualenvs/twisted-samples/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 85, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
  File "/Users/giacomo/.virtualenvs/twisted-samples/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/selectreactor.py", line 149, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = getattr(selectable, method)()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/Users/giacomo/.virtualenvs/twisted-samples/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 1435, in doRead
    protocol.makeConnection(transport)
  File "/Users/giacomo/.virtualenvs/twisted-samples/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/protocol.py", line 514, in makeConnection
    self.connectionMade()
  File "/Users/giacomo/pyenvs/twisted-samples/chat.py", line 13, in connectionMade
    self.sendLine("What's your name?")
  File "/Users/giacomo/.virtualenvs/twisted-samples/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/basic.py", line 636, in sendLine
    return self.transport.write(line + self.delimiter)
builtins.TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/giacomo/.virtualenvs/twisted-samples/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 103, in callWithLogger
    return callWithContext({"system": lp}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/giacomo/.virtualenvs/twisted-samples/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 86, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/giacomo/.virtualenvs/twisted-samples/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 122, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/giacomo/.virtualenvs/twisted-samples/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 85, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/Users/giacomo/.virtualenvs/twisted-samples/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/selectreactor.py", line 149, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = getattr(selectable, method)()
  File "/Users/giacomo/.virtualenvs/twisted-samples/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 243, in doRead
    return self._dataReceived(data)
  File "/Users/giacomo/.virtualenvs/twisted-samples/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 249, in _dataReceived
    rval = self.protocol.dataReceived(data)
  File "/Users/giacomo/.virtualenvs/twisted-samples/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/basic.py", line 572, in dataReceived
    why = self.lineReceived(line)
  File "/Users/giacomo/pyenvs/twisted-samples/chat.py", line 21, in lineReceived
    self.handle_GETNAME(line)
  File "/Users/giacomo/pyenvs/twisted-samples/chat.py", line 29, in handle_GETNAME
    self.sendLine("Welcome, %s!" % (name,))
  File "/Users/giacomo/.virtualenvs/twisted-samples/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/basic.py", line 636, in sendLine
    return self.transport.write(line + self.delimiter)
builtins.TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

My system Python is 2.7.16, version 3 is installed with `brew`.

If I need to post more info about my system, please let me know.

Comment: I want to add that I've created the exact same environment and made the same test with Parrot Linux (Debian distro). I got the same issue.

Comment: Same here learning in 2022. Did U solve this? I'm using copy/paste from the twisted website. I can't upgrade python either.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your issue:

```
    return self.transport.write(line + self.delimiter)
builtins.TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

You're mixing bytes and string values. What you get from the network is a `bytes` object and you will have to convert the `str` to `bytes`.  Also you cannot send `str` over the network. All sent data must be `bytes`. So assuming `self.delimiter` is the a string, you would just need to fix:

```
return self.transport.write(line + self.delimiter.decode("utf8"))
```

PS

No need to return on `self.transport.write()`. And you bring up a point that the docs are geared toward Python 2.7 and some of the examples don't work well for Python3+. This is a bug in my opinion. It's a good opportunity to contribute to Twisted ;)

Comment: Yes, I know twisted was primarly designed for Python 2.7 so it's reasonable some sample is outdated. Anyway the exception is raised in a framework source. I've tried to fix it with the line you suggest (without return), but I got this: `builtins.AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'`. Anyway thanks for your time!

Comment: Whoops. I always mix up `decode` and `encode`. It should be `self.delimiter.decode("utf8")`.

Comment: yes I've understood that and tried myself with `decode`. I got another error: `File "/Users/giacomo/.virtualenvs/twisted-samples/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/abstract.py", line 349, in write
    raise TypeError("Data must not be unicode")`. Anyway it's strange thing one have to fix package code instead of the sample one...